# Query or Function in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a **DB** in **SQLServer** in which there is a column called "Cell phones", the problem with that was that users entered their phone in two ways:

Form A: **0351-153111222**. In this case I need to remove the **0**, remove the **-** and remove the **15**, leaving as final form **3513111222**

Form B: **153111222**. In this case I need to remove the **1**5 and add at the beginning the **351** leaving as final form **3513111222**

As I do not want to update the entire table, I wanted to know if there is any query or function that allows me to **"accommodate"** or **"fix"** those forms so that they look like this:

Shape I want it to look like: **3513111222**

Comment: Google build a very good phonenumbers library. It's ported to multiple languages, see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/) for the C# port

Comment: Are you sure those are the only formats?

Comment: You can use the String Functions (Transact-SQL) to transform them into whatever format you want (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in SQL would be:

```
update t
    set phone = (case when phone like '0%-15%'
                      then stuff(replace(phone, '-15', ''), 1, 1, '')
                      when phone like '15%'
                      then stuff(phone, 1, 2, '')
                      else phone
                 end)
    where phone like '0%-15%' or phone like '15%';
```

This is a one-time fix though.  You should fix your data ingestion process to ensure that numbers are in the format you want.